# Turn jTable model into non-editable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I have a jTable that can be populated either manually or importing information from an Excel file.

My personalized isCellEditable() method is defined as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    if (column == HIDDEN_INDEX || column == AN_INDEX || column == ID_INDEX)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Therefore, there are three columns which are non-editable, independently how the user populates the table. However, I would like to **turn the whole table into non-editable if the user decides to import information from the Excel file**. What is the simplest way to perform this task?

Comment: please whats representing column == HIDDEN_INDEX, btw you are out of chances to good answer, everything are, could be, will be speculation, shorts to the dark, based on your quite empty question without good and clear code, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with JTable and hardcoded value for XxxTableModel as local variable

Comment: _turn the whole table into non-editable if the user decides to import information from the Excel file_ AFAIK you should maintain a flag. When the users clicks on import then check the status of the flag also  and return true/false in `isCellEditable method`.

Comment: @mKorbel the code is quite extense, it is MVC-based GUI, with a few components, not easy to extract a SSCCE piece of code. But the question is quite easy. How to turn a jTable into non-editable only in certain moments? I think the idea of using a flag is the same idea proposed in the next answer, i will try to work with that.

Comment: @boblinwien use case instead of if - else if - else, inside case to use if - else with boolean, or use default: return false

Comment: could you be more specific? I mean, too many statements in the same sentence, not clear for me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private boolean filledFromExcel;

public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    if (column == HIDDEN_INDEX || column == AN_INDEX || column == ID_INDEX)
        return false;
    else
        return !filledFromExcel;
}
```

Comment: I though the point was to make the whole table non-editable if imported from excel

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes it will... Can you point out what you mean?

Comment: No. Your right, I'm reading your your if statements backwards, my bad :P

Answer (score 0):

The following: YourJTable.setEditable(false); should work.

Comment: I would verify that if I was you